# SIGSEGV crashes on Android 5.0 Lollipop devices (and only them)

Tags: android, crash, gson, android-5.0-lollipop, ormlite

Our company have an Android app that's been out for a few months now, where very few crashes have been reported.

But with Lollipop upgrades being rolled out to our customers devices, we got reports about intermittent Segmentation fault (SIGSEGV) crashes. And the crashes only occur on Android 5.0 devices - like upgraded Samsung Galaxy 5, Sony Xperia Z3, new HTC devices (unsure of model name) and a few other. All Android 4+ devices runs our app without problems, but all tested Android 5 devices so far get these crashes.

We have been able to reproduce them, in the sense that we on our own devices get these crashes. But we have so far been able to locate the source of the crashes, or find a pattern in what causes them.

This one of the reported crash dumps:

```
    *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/klteactivexx/klteactive:5.0/LRX21T/xxxxxx:user/release-keys'
Revision: '8'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 8779, tid: 10227, name: hwuiTask2 >>> com.ourcompany.ourapp <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xbd04a008
r0 9d04a00c r1 b6f6b87c r2 9d04a000 r3 ffffffe2
r4 00000001 r5 07ffffff r6 00000002 r7 b6f6b894
r8 00000002 r9 fffffffc sl b6f6b87c fp 0000001f
ip 00000004 sp 9ee71a8c lr b6f37f4d pc b6f36a52 cpsr 00010030

backtrace:
#00 pc 0003ca52 /system/lib/libc.so (arena_run_reg_alloc+101)
#01 pc 0003df49 /system/lib/libc.so (je_arena_tcache_fill_small+96)
#02 pc 0004bad7 /system/lib/libc.so (je_tcache_alloc_small_hard+14)
#03 pc 000476af /system/lib/libc.so (je_malloc+302)
#04 pc 0000fa5f /system/lib/libc.so (malloc+10)
#05 pc 00000b09 /system/lib/libstdc++.so (operator new(unsigned int)+4)
#06 pc 000e2ecf /system/lib/libskia.so (SkPathRef::Editor::Editor(SkAutoTUnref<SkPathRef>*, int, int)+32)
#07 pc 000df1c1 /system/lib/libskia.so (SkPath::incReserve(unsigned int)+12)
#08 pc 000e0631 /system/lib/libskia.so (SkPath::addRRect(SkRRect const&, SkPath::Direction)+120)
#09 pc 000e0745 /system/lib/libskia.so (SkPath::addRoundRect(SkRect const&, float, float, SkPath::Direction)+76)
#10 pc 0003e6fd /system/lib/libhwui.so
#11 pc 0003e2ad /system/lib/libhwui.so
#12 pc 000314b3 /system/lib/libhwui.so
#13 pc 0001512b /system/lib/libhwui.so
#14 pc 0000ef11 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+112)
#15 pc 000602f5 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+72)
#16 pc 0000ea81 /system/lib/libutils.so
#17 pc 000137bb /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+30)
#18 pc 0001189b /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
```

We have no native code in the app written by ourself, and the only libs we're using besides the Android libs are GSon 2.3.1, Ormlite 4.48 and Spring 1.0.0.

I'm a bit unsure how to proceed with these errors, so any help would be welcome. I have seen suggestions to use NDK Stack Tool to translate the crash dump to something more readable, but with no pre-existing knowledge about NDK, I have so far not been able to get it to work in my dev enviroment (Windows7, Eclipse Kepler.

Anyone who has any similiar experiences when Android 5.0 upgrades started to roll out to customers, or have any ideas on how or where I should continue to look for the cause?

I guess NDK Stack Tool is my best hope, but I have so far been unable to find a good tutorial that get's me anywhere with it.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your specific question, unfortunately, but libskia.so is seriously broken in 5.0, e.g. decoding grayscale/mono-color PNGs either returns null or just crashes the app or device altogether.